# Visual Studio 2015: C++ decorations despite extern "C"

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to use an SDK from that I have a H and OBJ file. The H file declares all functions as extern "C", yet while linking, I get "Can't resolve external symbol _ibclr@4". The function is called ibclr and takes a 4B-parameter, so it looks like that's just the C++ decoration. But how is extern "C" not working?

Comment: We won't take a look at zip file. Paste a minimal example into the question box.

Answer (score 1):

`_ibclr@4` looks like `__stdcall` mangling, not C++ mangling.

Make sure to specify the correct calling convention in your declaration. If the library author didn't specify it, try `__cdecl`. If you're using Visual C++, it has a compiler option for the *default* calling convention, and the default for this option is `__cdecl`.